# Unable to install cube surfer addon by PyroEvil

Tags: add-on, installation

This is the error message I get every time I try to enable the cube surfer addon:

[image: error message]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry but i have already seen that post.
It did not help me. It is a different problem

Answer (score 0):

It should be an OS-related issue. this addon requires some higher Visual Studio Redistributable version installed, like [2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/Results.aspx?q=Microsoft%20Visual%20C%2B%2B%202010%20Redistributable&form=DLC) or [2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679). Then restart Blender, enable the addon again.

Comment: I have tried the above but it didn't help. Thank you for the suggestion though :)

Comment: Hmm, That's quite strange, I had exactly the same error message as yours, but it work for me. Probably it is something about your OS I suppose. Or try completely uninstall the Visual Studio Redistributable then reinstall.